# Debug JS code, why values updates without code execution

Tags: javascript, debugging

I debugged this JS code about LinkedList, i added first `1,2,3` after i added `4` at first place and finally, I used the function `insertAt` to add `5` at the position `(index=2)`. It finish this way: `{3{2{5{1{4}}}}}`

I cannot understand completely why when the line `previous.next = node;` executes, the value of `linkNumber` change to this order `{3{2{5{1{4}}}}}`. My first language was "C" and according to this, the code executes sequentially, so, why `linkNumber` updates if the function finish in `previous.next = node;` no more code executes after that.

Thanks in advance.

```
class Node {
    constructor(data, next = null) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}


class LinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }

    //Insert fisrt node
    insertFirst(data) {
        this.head = new Node(data, this.head);
        this.size++;
    }


    //Insert last node
    insertLast(data) {
        let node = new Node(data);
        let current;

        if (!this.head) {
            this.head = node;
        } else {
            current = this.head;
            while (current.next) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = node;
        }
        this.size++;
    }

    //Inser At index 
    insertAt(data, index) {
        if (index > 0 && index > this.size) {
            return;
        }

        if (index === 0) {
            this.head = new Node(data, this.head);
            return;
        }

        const node = new Node(data);
        let current, previous;

        //Set current to first
        current = this.head;
        let count = 0;

        while (count < index) {
            previous = current;
            count++;
            current = current.next;
        }

        node.next = current;
        previous.next = node;

        this.size++;
    }

    //Print data
    printListData() {
        let current = this.head;

        while (current) {
            console.log(current.data);
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

}

const linkNumber = new LinkedList();

linkNumber.insertFirst(1);
linkNumber.insertFirst(2);
linkNumber.insertFirst(3);
linkNumber.insertLast(4);
linkNumber.insertAt(5, 2)

linkNumber.printListData();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ9FW.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand what you think is non-sequential here. `
linkNumber.insertFirst(1);` through `
linkNumber.insertFirst(4);` evidently run first then `linkNumber.insertAt(5, 2)` runs and it finishes with adding `5` at position `2`. That is the sequence of operations you've defined. That is the sequence of operations that are performed. What do you think is missing or done extra?

Comment: Yes, you have a reason, is sequential, but something happens in parallel maybe, this is the part I cannot get. When `previous.next = node` executes I hope only the value of `previous` updates. However,  `linkNumber` updates too with the same code line. This is according to the debugger. My question is, why `LinkNumber` updates too if the line in execution is `previous.next = node`?

Comment: Because `linkNumbers` is simply the state of the entire linked list. There is no code to update it because its state is determined by its members. This would work the same in C - if you have a linked list `a -> b -> d` and insert `c` after `b` then the link is *immediately* `a -> b -> c -> d` as soon as you make that insertion. No update needed because that is the new state already.

Comment: None of the functions has an explicit `return` in the object (usually i see a return at the end of the function), then I've assumed `LinkedList` always return constructor values (`this.head` and `this.size`), a supposition which is correct according to the debugger, because of `insertFirst` return these values. Then, when `insertAt` executes I look at `this.head` and `size` values from beginning to the end. Now, `head` initial value's is `{3{2{1{4}}}}` and it depends on `current` (according to this line `current = this.head`) and `previous` depends on `current` (` previous = current`).

Comment: I noted in the line `previous.next = node` the value of the current is  `{1{4}}`, `node={5{1{4}}}`, `previous={2{1{4}}}` and `this.head={3{2{1{4}}}}`. In the next line, `previous.next = node` ,`current = {1{4}}`, `node={5{1{4}}}`, `previous={2{5{1{4}}}}` and `this.head={3{2{5{1}}}}`. But is in the last line which `this.head` updates, then if it depends on `current` or `previous`, why it did not update in loop while too.

I know is a very basic question, could you recommend some resources, blosgs, etc or the specific topic to understand how the complier executes the code.
Thanks a lot